# Whitespace node in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I was going through the book *XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0* by Michael Kay. I have gone through the topic of white space nodes. In this topic there is one example given.

```
<person>
  <name>Prudence Flowers</name>
  <employer>Lloyds Bank</employer>
  <place-of-work>
    71 Lombard Street
   London, UK
   <zip>EC3P 3BS</zip>
</place-of-work>
</person>
```

There are several text nodes present in the above XML.

- Between starting of the `<name>` element and end of the `<person>` element.
- Starting of the `<name>` and ending of the `<employer>` element
- Starting of the `<place-of-work>` element and end of the `<employer>` element
- End of the `<zip>` element and `</place-of-work>`.
- `</place-of-work>` element and `</person>` element

If the below stylesheet is the stylesheet to transform the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="person"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then my question is that if I execute the above XSLT file the it won't strip the whitespace node between the end of the `<zip>` element and `</place-of-work>`. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then my question is that If I execute the above XSLT file the it wont strip the white space node between theEnd of the Zip element and `</place-of-work>`. why?

Because the parent of that text node is the `place-of-work` element, not the `person` element, and `place-of-work` is not one of the elements that you have specified as `strip-space`.  The whitespace text nodes between `<person>` and `<name>` and between `</name>` and `<employer>` are direct children of the `person` element, so they will get stripped.

Comment: In that case If I specify <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> then it must remove that text node as well Am I right?

Comment: @Beast yes, `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` will tell it to remove _all_ whitespace-only text nodes in the whole document (unless countermanded by a more specific `xsl:preserve-space`).

Comment: Thanks actually I misunderstood the statement mentioned in the book. Thanks for the clarification budy.