# Simple XSLT where the IF test is failing

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a simple XML document that I'm trying to replace an element based on the element's value.

```
<document>
<meta>
    <wk_abc>
        UCM:SOURCE1
    </wk_abc>
    <wk_def>
        Other Text
    </wk_def>
    <wk_abc>
        UCM:SOURCE2
    </wk_abc>
</meta>
<content>
    Lorem ipsum
</content>
</document>
```

My XSL is this:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wk_abc">
   <xsl:if test=".='UCM:SOURCE1'">
        <bob>bob</bob>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

But it keeps failing the IF condition. and skipping over the replacement element.  Why is this test failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there is whitespace either side of 'UCM:SOURCE1' in the node.

Try changing your `xsl:if` condition to this to remove the white-space before doing the check:

```
  <xsl:if test="normalize-space()='UCM:SOURCE1'">
```

Note that this does more than just trim the white space. If the text was `UCM:SOURCE1     UCMSOURCE2` for example, the whitepsaces in the middle would be merged into one single space, so normalize-space would return `UCM:SOURCE1 UCMSOURCE2`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use *contains()* for example:

```
<xsl:if test="contains(., 'UCM:SOURCE1')">
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a whitespace issue. If I change your input file to 

`<document>
<meta>
    <wk_abc>UCM:SOURCE1</wk_abc>
    <wk_def>
        Other Text
    </wk_def>
    <wk_abc>
        UCM:SOURCE2
    </wk_abc>
</meta>
<content>
    Lorem ipsum
</content>
</document>`

If the input document had spaces they are preserved. If you want further control of spaces processing use, xsl-strip construct. 
Look at the articles below on how to granularly control whitespace processing:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipwhitesp/

There are some earlier suggestions in stackoverflow on how to use these constructs:
[Whitespace node in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245557/whitespace-node-in-xslt)

You may also try normalize-space as suggested in:
[How to Trim in xslt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409482/how-to-trim-in-xslt/11570818#11570818)

From the XSLT spec(http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip):

> After the tree for a source document or stylesheet document has been constructed, but before it is otherwise processed by XSLT, some text nodes are stripped. A text node is never stripped unless it contains only whitespace characters. Stripping the text node removes the text node from the tree. The stripping process takes as input a set of element names for which whitespace must be preserved. The stripping process is applied to both stylesheets and source documents, but the set of whitespace-preserving element names is determined differently for stylesheets and for source documents.